# Swapping records in a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following table in a mysql db:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_defaults` (
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `i1` text,
  `i2` text,
  `i3` text,
  `i4` text,
  `i5` text,
  `i6` text,
  `i7` text,
  `i8` text,
  `i9` text,
  `i10` text,
  `row` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `graphkind` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `graphtitle` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'test',
  `keys` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
  `vertical` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `size` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `more1` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `more2` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`row`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

And some data for it:

```
INSERT INTO `user_defaults` (`user_id`, `i1`, `i2`, `i3`, `i4`, `i5`, `i6`, `i7`, `i8`, `i9`, `i10`, `row`, `graphkind`, `graphtitle`, `keys`, `vertical`, `size`, `more1`, `more2`) VALUES
(2, 'YEAR|Y.E. Q1F15', 'AREA|TOTAL ITALY', 'MOMENT|TOTALE MOMENTO', 'OFF PREMISE|OFF PREMISE§ON PREMISE|ON PREMISE§TOTAL|ON+OFF PREMISE', 'TOTAL|TOTAL PACKS', 'OCCASION|TOTAL OCCASION', 'BEER BY BRAND|BECK''S§BEER BY BRAND|DREHER§BEER BY BRAND|HEINEKEN§BEER BY BRAND|MORETTI§BEER BY BRAND|NASTRO AZZURRO§BEER BY BRAND|PERONI§BEER BY BRAND|TOURTEL', 'MEASURES|CONSUMERS 18+ (.000)§MEASURES|PENETRATION VS UNIVERSE§MEASURES|VOLUME (HL)', NULL, NULL, 1, 'col', 'Test', 'i1,i2,i3,i5,i6,i8,i4,i7', 1, '', '', ''),
(2, 'YEAR|Y.E. Q1F15', 'AREA|TOTAL ITALY', 'MOMENT|TOTALE MOMENTO', 'TOTAL|ON+OFF PREMISE', 'TOTAL|TOTAL PACKS', 'OCCASION|TOTAL OCCASION', 'TOTAL|TOTAL BEVERAGE', 'MEASURES|CONSUMERS 18+ (.000)', NULL, NULL, 2, 'line', 'Test', 'i1,i2,i4,i3,i5,i6,i8,i7', 1, '', '', ''),
(2, 'YEAR|Y.E. Q1F15', 'AREA|TOTAL ITALY', 'MOMENT|TOTALE MOMENTO', 'TOTAL|ON+OFF PREMISE', 'TOTAL|TOTAL PACKS', 'OCCASION|TOTAL OCCASION', 'BEER BY BRAND|TOTAL BEER BY BRAND§BEER BY BRAND|PERONI§BEER BY BRAND|MORETTI§BEER BY BRAND|NASTRO AZZURRO§BEER BY BRAND|HEINEKEN§BEER BY BRAND|BECK''S§BEER BY BRAND|DREHER§BEER BY BRAND|TOURTEL', 'MEASURES|CONSUMERS 18+ (.000)', NULL, NULL, 3, 'col', 'Pippe poppe peppe', 'i1,i2,i4,i3,i6,i5,i8,i7', 4, 's50', '', ''),
(12, 'TRIM|Q1 F13§TRIM|Q2 F13§TRIM|Q3 F13§TRIM|Q4 F13', 'AREA|TOTAL ITALY', 'BEER|BEER§BEER|PERONI', 'TOTAL|TOTAL PLACES', 'OCCASION|CONSUMPTION TOTAL OCCASION', 'MEASURE|VOLUMIZ', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 'col', 'Overview', 'i3,i2,i4,i5,i6,i1', 1, '', '', ''),
(13, 'TRIM|Q1 F13§TRIM|Q2 F13§TRIM|Q3 F13§TRIM|Q4 F13', 'AREA|TOTAL ITALY', 'BEER|BEER§BEER|PERONI', 'TOTAL|TOTAL PLACES', 'OCCASION|CONSUMPTION TOTAL OCCASION', 'MEASURE|VOLUMIZ', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 'col', 'Overview', 'i3,i2,i4,i5,i6,i1', 1, '', '', ''),
(35, 'QUARTER|Q1F15', 'AREA|TOTAL ITALY', 'MOMENT|TOTALE MOMENTO', 'OFF PREMISE|OFF PREMISE§ON PREMISE|ON PREMISE§TOTAL|ON+OFF PREMISE', 'TOTAL|TOTAL PACKS', 'OCCASION|TOTAL OCCASION', 'BEVERAGE ON+OFF|APERITIVES§BEVERAGE ON+OFF|BEER§BEVERAGE ON+OFF|CSD§BEVERAGE ON+OFF|FRUIT JUICES§BEVERAGE ON+OFF|OTHER BEVERAGE§BEVERAGE ON+OFF|PROSECCO, CHAMPAGNE§BEVERAGE ON+OFF|RTD TEA§BEVERAGE ON+OFF|SPIRITS+COCKTAIL§BEVERAGE ON+OFF|SPORT+ENERGY DRINKS§BEVERAGE ON+OFF|TOTAL BEVERAGE ON+OFF§BEVERAGE ON+OFF|WATER§BEVERAGE ON+OFF|WINE§TOTAL|TOTAL BEVERAGE', 'MEASURES|CONSUMERS 18+ (.000)§MEASURES|PENETRATION VS UNIVERSE§MEASURES|VOLUME (HL)', NULL, NULL, 2, 'line', 'Beverage - SHARE OFF STOMACH', 'i1,i2,i7,i4,i3,i6,i5,i8', 1, '', '', ''),
(35, 'QUARTER|Q1F15', 'AREA|TOTAL ITALY', 'MOMENT|TOTALE MOMENTO', 'OFF PREMISE|OFF PREMISE§ON PREMISE|ON PREMISE§TOTAL|ON+OFF PREMISE', 'TOTAL|TOTAL PACKS', 'OCCASION|TOTAL OCCASION', 'BEER BY BRAND|BECK''S§BEER BY BRAND|DREHER§BEER BY BRAND|HEINEKEN§BEER BY BRAND|MORETTI§BEER BY BRAND|NASTRO AZZURRO§BEER BY BRAND|PERONI§BEER BY BRAND|TOTAL BEER BY BRAND§BEER BY BRAND|TOURTEL', 'MEASURES|CONSUMERS 18+ (.000)§MEASURES|PENETRATION VS UNIVERSE§MEASURES|VOLUME (HL)', NULL, NULL, 3, 'line', 'Beer - SHARE OFF STOMACH', 'i1,i2,i7,i4,i3,i6,i5,i8', 1, '', '', '');
```

The relevant fields that identify a record are user_id and row, and I wrote a PHP editor that lets a user modify records as he wants. Records of a certain user (user_id) are shown and sorted by the "row" field.

Now I have added "MOVE UP"/"MOVE DOWN" buttons to swap two records together.

Essentially I only need to swap the "row" fields of two records:

```
UPDATE user_defaults SET row=1 WHERE user_id=xxx AND row=2
UPDATE user_defaults SET row=2 WHERE user_id=xxx AND row=1
```

of course this won't work as after the first line I would have both records with row=1 (an error as keys are unique) and after the second line they would both end up with row=2

My question: is there a way I can swap rows with SQL (or PHP) at the same time? Possibly keeping the query independent of the number and kind of fields in the table (except user_id and row)?

I mean, if possible, not like this:

```
UPDATE user_defaults SET i1=..,i2=..,i3=... WHERE user_id=xxx AND row=1
// (values from row 2)
UPDATE user_defaults SET i1=..,i2=..,i3=... WHERE user_id=xxx AND row=2
// (values from row 1)
```

(copy all the fields of one row into the other except row, but I would have to write all fields in the query and modify it every time a field is added..)

Comment: Records in MySQL have no natural sort order, so assigning a spot in the table does not guarantee you will always get the records in the same order unless you specifically order the table (using ORDER BY). Why are you wanting to do this?

Comment: @JayBlanchard order is the row field: `ORDER BY row ASC`, what I need is to swap `row`s

Comment: Actually, the real reason your "swap rows" queries won't work is that the first one will throw an error due to duplicate primary key values.  Your comment about having to rewrite your programming code if you add fields to your table suggests that a look at your database design might be in order.

Comment: You would have to recalculate *all* rows every time you move one row unless you are doing a one for one swap. You have to get another unique identifier from the rows to be swapped and use that identifier to run your update queries with.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I want to do a one for one swap, juast swap row 1 with row 2

Comment: Then you have to get a unique identifier, other than the row field, to do your updates with.

Comment: @JayBlanchard ugh,that's ugly, no other way? You mean "move row 2 to row 999 then row 1 to row 2 than row 999 to row 1" like swapping vars in a programming language?

Comment: Pretty much - there is no function available to make the swap.